# Oracle APEX Application MERGE statement - ORA-06550 subprogram or cursor is out of scope

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to write a MERGE statement for an Oracle APEX Application. The user fills out a form, which should insert if the unique column STVSBGI_CODE does not exist, and update if STVSBGI_CODE does exist. Here's the MERGE as I've written it:

```
MERGE INTO UA_SATURN.SWBSBGI U
USING (SELECT :P5_STVSBGI_CODE, :P5_STATE_CODE, :P5_NCES_SCHOOL_ID, :P5_NCES_DISTRICT_ID, :APP_USER FROM DUAL) V
ON (U.STVSBGI_CODE = V.STVSBGI_CODE)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    U.STATE_CODE = :P5_STATE_CODE,
    U.NCES_SCHOOL_ID = :P5_NCES_SCHOOL_ID,
    U.NCES_DISTRICT_ID = :P5_NCES_DISTRICT_ID,
    U.ACTIVITY_DATE = SYSDATE,
    U.USER_ID = :APP_USER,
    U.ACTIVE_IND = 'Y'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
(
    U.STVSBGI_CODE,
    U.STATE_CODE,
    U.NCES_SCHOOL_ID,
    U.NCES_DISTRICT_ID,
    U.ACTIVITY_DATE,
    U.USER_ID,
    U.ACTIVE_IND
)
VALUES
(
    :P5_STVSBGI_CODE,
    :P5_STATE_CODE,
    :P5_NCES_SCHOOL_ID,
    :P5_NCES_DISTRICT_ID,
    SYSDATE,
    :APP_USER,
    'Y'
);
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
1 error has occurred
ORA-06550: line 4, column 22: PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'V' reference is out of
scope ORA-06550: line 4, column 22: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in
call to 'STVSBGI_CODE' ORA-06550: line 4, column 22: PL/SQL: ORA-00904:
"V"."STVSBGI_CODE": invalid identifier ORA-06550: line 2, column 1: PL/SQL: SQL
Statement ignored
```

Comment: You need to alias the columns in the SELECT statement so it can be used in the JOIN e.g. `SELECT :P5_STVSBGI_CODE AS STVSBGI_CODE, ...`

Comment: That did it! If you write that as an answer, I'll accept it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: A word of advice (not related to your problem, but nevertheless): I wouldn't use 'V' as an alias in recent Oracle databases, because they already contain a PUBLIC SYNONYM `V` for a function in the APEX_... schema. This can get very confusing if you mis-spell a column name (you'll get a PLS-306 instead of the usual ORA-00904).

Comment: Okay, I'll use a different letter. Thanks for the warning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to alias the columns in the SELECT statement so it can be used in the JOIN e.g.

```
SELECT :P5_STVSBGI_CODE AS STVSBGI_CODE, ...
```

Thanks!